# In React useCallback hook, From where does the parameters come inside the callback function

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

Suppose i have a useCallback function like this

```
export const useMenu = (id1, id2, id3) => useCallback(({row, column, id}, myProps) => {
    doSomething()
}, [id1, id2, id3]);
```

And I'm calling the `useMenu` function like this

```
const myMenu = useMenu(123, 345, 567);
```

So i just wanted to understand from where am i getting this **row**, **column** and **myProps's** value?

Comment: You can't use `useCallback` like this... Read about rules of hooks, this code is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're parameters that must get passed to the `myMenu` function when invoked later, eg with `myMenu({ row: 123 })`. See below snippet for an example:

```js
const useMenu = (id1, id2, id3) => React.useCallback(({row, column, id}, myProps) => {
    console.log('got row of', row);
}, [id1, id2, id3]);
const App = ({ id1, id2, id3 }) => {
  const myMenu = useMenu(123, 345, 567);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    myMenu({ row: 123 });
  }, []);
  
  return 'app';
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

For your code, look to see what calls `myMenu` to see exactly where the parameters come from.

Comment: Ok. Now i understood, myMenu itself is a function where i'll be passing those parameters. Thanks :)